# Query to get the lowest date difference for several date sets

Tags: mysql

I have a table named tasks and another named activities. The tasks table has a name and a keyid column. Activities has a date field and a task field that relates to only one row in the tasks table (if activities.task column is equal to tasks.keyid column, then the activity is for that task). However one task can have many activities. What I want is query that returns the name of the task and the difference between the current day and the newest activity for that task.

To give a better idea this query gives me what I want for task with keyid 10:

```
SELECT t.name, MIN(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),a.adate)), t.keyid  FROM tasks AS t, activities AS a WHERE (t.keyid='10') AND (a.task = t.keyid);
```

However I do not know how to get the same thing for ALL tasks. So If I have 10 tasks, I would need 10 results with the task name and the day difference between today and the newest activity for that task.

How would I write this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join tasks table with the last activities of the task

```
SELECT t.name, DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),a.adate), t.keyid  
FROM tasks t JOIN activities a 
ON a.task = t.keyid
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 'a'
                 FROM activities a2
                 WHERE a2.task = a.task
                 AND a2.date > a.date
                )
```

Comment: This has worked. However I do not understand the query. Can you explain everything after AND NOT EXISTS, please? Thank you.

Comment: Simply not exists another activity a2 which have the same task of the activity a where a2.date is greater then a.date. So if a2 NOT exists activity a is the last one and the table task will be joined with table activity on the row a.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it was something like that but I have never seen that syntaxis before, so I wasn't sure. Thanks again.